# Deserializing elemets with JSON.NET and generated classes

Tags: c#, json

I have json file:

```
    [
       {
          "as_of":"2012-08-31T15:31:55Z",
          "trends":[
             {
                "name":"#GDTHATXX",
             },
             {
                "name":"#UnMundoEnElQue",
             }
          ],
          "created_at":"2012-08-31T15:30:32Z",
          "locations":[
             {
                "name":"Globales",
                "woeid":1
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
```

And generated classes:

```
public class Trend
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int woeid { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string as_of { get; set; }
    public List<Trend> trends { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public List<Location> locations { get; set; }
}
```

I can deserialize elemets in RootObject like this:

```
 List<RootObject> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(Text);
            lvMain3.ItemsSource = values;
```

But how can deserialize element from "trends" or "locations". Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't they get deserialized?

Comment: Element from RootObject deserializing but ehen i writing List<Trend> it don't deserializing

Comment: If deserialization works, why don't you call `values[0].trends` or `values[0].locations` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inner elements are being deserialized together with the RootObject, so after executing

```
List<RootObject> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(Text);
```

You can access both  "trends" and "locations" elements from values variable.
Of course you can use linq to access specific items from the lists:

```
values.First().trends.First().name;
```

Or something like this.